# key pair array adding same value in loop python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I am adding value in array in for loop but it is adding same value in loop again and again.
 here is my code:

```
for document in activityData:
    activityInfo.append(document)
for document in activityInfo:
    actRegCount = actregM.countAppliedReg(str(document['_id']),timeInt)
    if (not document['owner'] in ownerIds) and (document['deleted']==0):
        ownerIds['a']=str(document['owner'])
        ownerIds['b']=actRegCount
        ownerIds['c']=0
    array.append(ownerIds)
```

and

```
for document in jobData:
    jobInfo.append(document)
for document in jobInfo:
    jobApplyCount = jobApplyM.countAppliedJob(str(document['_id']),timeInt)
    if (not document['owner'] in ownerIds) and (document['deleted']==0):
        ownerIds['a']=str(document['owner'])
        ownerIds['b']=0
        ownerIds['c']=str(jobApplyCount)
    array.append(ownerIds)
```

but it adds same value again and again.

Output:

```
[{'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'},
 {'a': '55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'b': 0, 'c': '0'}]
```

I am new to python so may be it is a silly error. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Your `array.append(ownerIds)` is outside `if` statement. That means for cases where if condition returns false, it will append same values to the array

Comment: Also you put `document['owner']` in `ownerIds['a']`. So, shouldn't`document['owner'] in ownerIds` always return false?

Comment: @kuro thnkx for help but I couldn't understand your last comment. Could u explain more plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [copy](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) your `OwnerId` in your `append` (and put the `append` in the `if`):

```
import copy

for document in jobData:
    jobInfo.append(document)
for document in jobInfo:
    jobApplyCount = jobApplyM.countAppliedJob(str(document['_id']),timeInt)
    if (not document['owner'] in ownerIds) and (document['deleted']==0):
        ownerIds['a']=str(document['owner'])
        ownerIds['b']=0
        ownerIds['c']=str(jobApplyCount)
        array.append(copy.deepcopy(ownerIds))
```

Comment: thnkx for help. I have no idea about deepcopy. Could u explain more about it.